# Failed: Unexpected value 'TreeviewConfig' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation in unit test

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, treeview, ngx-treeview

I am trying to test a component containing ngx-treeview. I wrote the following test, but it fails with the error message contained in the title (obviously except the in unit test part):

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TreeviewConfig, TreeviewItem, TreeviewModule } from 'ngx-treeview';

import { TabTreeviewComponent } from './tab-treeview.component';

describe('TabTreeviewComponent', () => {
  let component: TabTreeviewComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TabTreeviewComponent>;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TabTreeviewComponent ],
      imports: [ TreeviewConfig, TreeviewItem, TreeviewModule.forRoot() ],
      providers: [  ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));



  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TabTreeviewComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const config = TreeviewConfig.create({​​
      hasAllCheckBox: false,
      hasFilter: true,
      hasCollapseExpand: true,
      maxHeight: 435
    }​​);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I already tried initializing the TreeviewConfig as a declaration without any avail apparently. I also tried providing it as a provider - that also did not help at all... I am unsure what else could I try at this point, TestBed must have a way to include the config for the TreeView somehow or am I making a logical fallacy here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is being thrown because you are including non modules on the `inports` array

Basically you only need to import `TreeviewModule`

```typescript
 imports: [ TreeviewModule.forRoot() ],
```

Comment: Is the .forRoot() necessary? What does it do?

Comment: `forRoot()` is important. Some features will not work if you do not include it